# How to reduce blank space between legend and edge of the window?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have this code:

```
ggplot(subset(sub, paired =='1'), aes(cond, fill = corr)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill")+
  theme_minimal()+
  xlab ('Тест') +
  ylab ('Доля ответов') +
  facet_wrap(biling_type~biling_group, 1, labeller=labeller(paired = c('1'= 'Парные', "0" = "Непарные"), biling_type = labels1, biling_group = labels2)) +
  labs(title="Парные понятия")+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size=12), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.x  = element_text(size=14),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=14),
        axis.text.y  = element_text(size=14),
        legend.title = element_text(size=14),
        legend.text = element_text(size=14))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1))+
  scale_x_discrete (labels = c("Житейский", "Научный"))+
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Правильность употребления",
                    labels=c("Правильное", "Неправильное"))
```

And this plot:
[image]

It seems that because of some legend features there's a blank space between the plot and the edge of the window. And titles aren't fully shown.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but using the `margin` option in `axis.title.x` and `axis.title.y` might be what you're looking for. Here's a sample from one of my charts: `axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 6, r = 0, b = 2, l = 0))`. Using `hjust` in `axis.text.x` and `axis.text.y` might be helpful too: `axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=1)`. Hope that helps.

Comment: @trijamms, See all that whitespace to the right of the legend? OP and I want to reduce that. I've tried your suggestion and it hasn't worked.